# Is "overnight tonight" redundant?

Tags: meaning, grammar, redundancy

I use the term "overnight tonight" regularly but also understand how it can be perceived as redundant. For me, "overnight" means passing from one day to another. While "tonight" signifies the current, present night.

Therefore, when I use "tonight" after "overnight" it clarifies the overnight I am referring to is the present one. Otherwise it would be "overnight Wednesday into Thursday" or "overnight Wednesday."

I also wonder if its syntax dependent. For example if I have not yet signified or mentioned the day then is it more acceptable?

Comment: Can you give an example sentence?

Comment: "I'll be staying there overnight". Oh yes? Which night would that be?

Answer (score 2):

'Overnight tonight' or 'overnight (tonight)' is certainly needed as a clarification in some sentences:

- 'These new tablets I'd like you to try may result in sleeplessness overnight'

may refer to a possible one-off or a continuing side effect.

However, I'd probably rephrase here instead.

Most dictionaries don't explicitly bring out the possibility that 'overnight' may refer to either 'at night in general' or 'during the whole of or at some point/s during **this** night'.

[OLD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/overnight_1), for instance, just has

> **overnight** [adverb]:
>
> ​ during or for the night
>
> - *We stayed overnight in London after the theatre.*

But 'the night' may be identifying (the night after the theatre performance) or generic (as in, for example, 'a creature of the night').

An internet example of the broader usage of 'overnight':

- ... *the defender regularly stayed overnight at Treetops* [[Scotcourts.gov.uk](https://scotcourts.gov.uk/docs/default-source/cos-general-docs/pdf-docs-for-opinions/2022-sac-(civ)-012.pdf?sfvrsn=9a561970_1)]

As in these two examples, context usually disambiguates.

Comment: "Tonight" often refers to the evening although it can mean the whole night (see e.g. [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tonight)), so adding "overnight" would clarify that.